# File Validation and ValidationError

Tags: python, django, mime-types

I am validating a file mime type in one of my forms and raising a ValidationError if the check fails. The problem is that even when the check passes, a ValidationError is displayed and I'm unsure as to why. Code below.

forms.py

```
def clean_video(self):
    file = self.cleaned_data.get('video', False)
    valid = 'no'
    if file:
        import mimetypes
        mimetypes.init()
        mime = mimetypes.guess_type(str(file))
        if str(mime[0]) == 'video/mp4':
            valid = 'yes'
            return file, valid
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('File type not supported. Please upload a file of type .mp4.'))
    return file, valid
```

`mime` ends up being `('video/mp4', None)` on a correct file type upload but still raises the ValidationError and this is where I'm confused. Please halp!

Comment: Code-wise this seems perfectly fine. You sure that exactly this piece of code throws ValidationError and it's not coming from anywhere else?

Comment: I think it may have something to do with Djangos `UploadedFile` and `InMemoryUploadedFile` classes. If I upload a file with a type other than .mp4, the error is displayed correctly in the template, otherwise, I get the Django debug screen displaying the error with a `mime type` of `('None', 'None')`. I really don't like taking form logic to the view, but I'm thinking that may be the best workaround for this.

Comment: Take it a step higher, check what `file` is there.. Ow, btw.. `file` is of course a built-in type of python. Try renaming the variable to something like `uploaded_file`, maybe just this confuses type detectors..

Comment: I think the time may be getting to me. `form.is_valid()` will run the `clean_somefieldname()` functions automatically won't it? If so, it's been doing it correctly this entire time and I have been calling it explicitly a second time and I guess that would cause the error.

Comment: Yes sir, it sure will be :)

Comment: Ayooo it's 2:15am and I've been battling with my own sleep deprivation induced stupidity. `form.is_valid()` does call `clean_somefieldname()` automatically. All is well. Code is fine. Sleep is good. Thanks @favoretti